# Linq request make a lot of queries to DB

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have ef classes like this:

```
class Product 
{
  public int ProductId {set; get;}
...
 public List<ProductBannedIn> BannedIn;
}

public class ProductBannedIn
{
  public int ProductId {set; get;}
  public Product Product {set; get;}
  public int CountryId {set; get;}
  public Country Country {set; get;}
}
```

And want to make request like:

```
... //query - added some filters before
var products = query.Include(x => x.BannedIn)
    .Join(context.ProductTranslation
        .Where(x => x.LanguageId == language.LanguageId),
           product => product.ProductId,
              translation => translation.Product.ProductId,
                  (x,y) => new {
                      Id = x. ProductId,
                      Name = y.Name,
                      Description = y.Description,
                      Type = x.TypeId,
                      BannedIn = x.BannedIn.Select(b => b.CountryId),
                   }).ToList();
```

Problem: Problem is that when I fetch for example 1000 products this part

```
BannedIn = x.BannedIn.Select(b => b.CountryId)
```

make query for every row and its very slow.
What I seen in debugger that for each product make query to fetch BannedIn, but should be already fetched cause I have Include

What need to be achieved:
In general should be like 1 query to db and not for each row (x.BannedIn)

Comment: you need to materialize see may answer, if that resolve you question please upvote and mark as resolved ;)

Comment: Just curious.  You are using EF but instead of using Nav properties and an EF structured selection (INCLUDEs etc), you did LINQ and gained nothing from using EF.  Why?

Comment: @JohnWhite in this part of code I generate new anonymous entity for response, so I can't just return all entity (Product has fields that thought be returns and I maintain multi language)

Comment: @ArkhypKoshel I saw that.  It can also be accomplished by mapping or a LINQ Select() once the initial data acquisition has completed.  Most likely you are using that "new" entity somewhere else.  In that case predefining an interface DTO object would make sense.  As Ivan pointed out below, 2.1 has improved query translation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a known (so called N + 1 query) issue with correlated subqueries in pre 2.1 EF Core versions. It's been fixed in 2.1 - see [New features in EF Core 2.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-2.1) - [Optimization of correlated subqueries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-2.1#optimization-of-correlated-subqueries):

> We have improved our query translation to avoid executing "N + 1" SQL queries in many common scenarios in which the usage of a navigation property in the projection leads to joining data from the root query with data from a correlated subquery. The optimization requires buffering the results from the subquery, and we require that you modify the query to opt-in the new behavior.

So upgrade to the latest EF Core bits if possible and then "opt-in" for the optimization by adding `.ToList()` to the correlated subquery as explained in the documentation link:

```
BannedIn = x.BannedIn.Select(b => b.CountryId).ToList(),
```

The result will be execution of 2 SQL queries (this is how EF Core works with correlated collections - 1 SQL query per collection), but not 1 per each product as currently.

Answer (score 0):

I just updated ef packages, and everything is working good